# The constructor UiDevice() is not visible

Tags: java, android, superclass

I am getting the error message for the following code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiDevice;
import com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase;

public class TestTarget extends UiDevice {
    TestTarget() {
        super();
    }
    public ArrayList<TestTargetView> testTargetViews;
```

}

Comment: get rid of constructor (since you do not doing something new there) or make it public

Comment: @Selvin if i remove the constructor im getiing "Implicit super constructor UiDevice() is not visible for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor".
2) If i add public to the constructor it still shows the same error.

Comment: UiDevice has a private constructor. You cannot call super() on it.

Comment: @dymmeh so what is the solution?

Comment: UiDevice cannot be extended. There's no way around it. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.